# Error in file(file, "rt") R arguments

Tags: r

i am using below RScript.

```
/usr/local/bin/R CMD BATCH --slave '--args 51102' coverage_db/src/main/scripts/R_ExonsPlots.R
```

R Script as follows

```
args<-commandArgs(TRUE)
gname = as.numeric(args[1])
sample_data = read.table(Sys.glob("/NGS_STORE/ARCHIVE2/Cov_InputBed_Repository/*gname*"),sep="\t",header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(sample_data)=c("chr","start","end","gene","avg_depth")
```

Error

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

It worked fine without "arguments"
but could not get what the error is

Comment: Do you just want to know about `paste`

Comment: I am not sure what "paste" does.I am new to R programming. wanted to Glob the file based on "args" to read table.

Comment: try to print value of `gname`.  I think you must be getting more than one value in `gname` which is invoking this error.  One more question why you need to pass '--args 51102' will just 51102 not do. You are anyway doing `as.numeric` below.

Comment: I printed "gname" its only one value. How do i pass "51101" as an argument if not 'R CMD BATCH --slave '--args 51102' R_ExonsPlots.R '', I looked through other similar error answers isnt clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

The error results from `read.table` because multiple filenames are returned by the `Sys.glob`. In this case, `Sys.glob` will return a vector of characters, one for each file name matching the wildcard. Most likely, this problem is triggered by the other problem where the value for gname is actually not used since `"/NGS_STORE/ARCHIVE2/Cov_InputBed_Repository/*gname*"` is just a string (characters). To fix both:

```
args<-commandArgs(TRUE)
gname = as.numeric(args[1])
files = Sys.glob(paste0("/NGS_STORE/ARCHIVE2/Cov_InputBed_Repository/*",gname,"*"))
if (!is.na(files[1])) {
  sample_data = data.frame()
  for (afile in files) {
      sample_data = rbind(sample_data, read.table(afile, sep="\t", header=FALSE,
                                                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
  }
  colnames(sample_data)=c("chr","start","end","gene","avg_depth")
}
```

Here, I'm assuming that if there are multiple files satisfying the glob, you want to combine them by rows (i.e., they have the same number of columns). Obviously, you can combine them by columns, ignore all but the first, etc.

Note that if there are no matches for the glob, then it will return `NA`. That is why we need to check for `NA` before calling `read.table`. Otherwise, you will get the `read.table` error `Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection`.