# Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument when running R script

Tags: r

I am trying to reproduce this protocol for DNA sequencing data analysis. It requires running this bash script that links to an R script. However, I am getting this error (see bottom) that I cant seem to solve.

```
#!/bin/bash

Project_dir=~/base
cd /${Project_dir}
SCRTP=~/scRepliseq-Pipeline
OUTNAME="bam/G1_F121_A1.adapter_filtered2"
genome_name="mm10"
bamfile=${OUTNAME}.${genome_name}.clean_srt_markdup.bam
rscript=${SCRTP}/util/Step3_R-Aneu-Fragment-bins.R
out_dir="Aneu_analysis"
Name=‘$bamfile’
Name=${name%.adapter_filtered2.${genome_name}.clean_srt_markdup.bam}
blacklist=~/blacklist/mm10-blacklist-v1_id.bed
genome_file=~/reference/UCSC_hg19_female.fa.fai
mkdir -p ${out_dir}
Rscript --vanilla $rscript ${bamfile} ${out_dir} ${name} ${blacklist} ${genome_file}
```

it links to this R script

```
args = commandArgs(TRUE)
bamfile=args[1]
out_dir=args[2]
name=args[3]
blacklist=args[4]
genome_file=args[5]
options(scipen=100)

##Extension of file name##
ext="_mapq10_blacklist_fragment.Rdata"
ext2="_mapq10_blacklist_bin.Rdata"

library(AneuFinder)

##loading black list and genome Info##
genome_tmp <- read.table(genome_file,sep="\t") #UCSC_mm9.woYwR.fa.fai
genome=data.frame(UCSC_seqlevel=genome_tmp$V1,UCSC_seqlength=genome_tmp$V2)
chromosomes=as.character(genome$UCSC_seqlevel)

##setup output directories##
out_dir_f=paste0(out_dir,"/fragment")
out_dir_b=paste0(out_dir,"/bins")
dir.create(out_dir,showWarnings = FALSE)
dir.create(out_dir_f,showWarnings = FALSE)
dir.create(out_dir_b,showWarnings = FALSE)

##save the fragment file (>10 MAPQ), filtering out the blacklist regions##
raw_reads=bam2GRanges(bamfile,remove.duplicate.reads = TRUE,min.mapq = 10,blacklist = blacklist)
save(raw_reads,file = paste0(out_dir_f,"/",name,ext))

##save the bin data file ##
bins_reads=binReads(raw_reads,
                    assembly=genome,
                    chromosomes=chromosomes,
                    binsizes=c(40000,80000,100000,200000,500000))

rpm=1000000/length(raw_reads)
bins_reads[["rpm"]]=rpm
save(bins_reads,file=paste(out_dir_b,"/",name,ext2,sep=""))
```

It shows this error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
Calls: read.table -> file
Execution halted
```

Comment: The first thing I did was look in your R script for an argument called 'description', but I cannot see one. I suspect the easiest way to solve would be to open R/RStudio and run the R code line by line until you see the error, then you'll know precisely which line caused it.

Comment: I see [`read.table()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38908279/5783745) *can* cause that same error message, so that might be what's causing it. In the linked example, it's happening because the file it's supposed to read in is >1 item long. Here's an example `read.table(c("one", "two")) # Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument`. But that's really a guess, you should run line by line and identify which line is causing it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ive been able to reproduce the error when running the line ` genome_tmp <- read.table(genome_file,sep="\t") #UCSC_mm9.woYwR.fa.fai
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument ` @stevec

Comment: In that case, can you run `genome_file` see what it returns?

Comment: Thanks, here is what I get  ´genome_file [1] NA`    @stevec

Comment: In R, can you run `args` and show what it returns (it may be a bit messy but that's okay). Also can you run `length(args)` and show what it returns.

Comment: This might be worth a shot. Try replacing the top line `args = commandArgs(TRUE)` with `args = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)`

Comment: Sorry, try this `args = commandArgs(trailingOnly = FALSE)` (setting to TRUE is what you had in the original). This is just a guess btw..

Comment: Thanks again, this has given a few more details

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
Calls: read.table -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '--file=/home/jah/scRepliseq-Pipeline/util/Step3_R-Aneu-Fragment-bins4.R': No such file or directory
Execution halted

Comment: Can you try the following: comment out the entire R script, and at the very top, on line 1, place this `print(args)`, and on line 2, place this `print(paste("Length of args is:", length(args))`. Then run it and it should print the args to the screen, and you'll be able to quickly tell if they're going through into the R script correctly. (if you want to screenshot the result and add it to your question, that would probably help)

Comment: so this is what I get

`function (name)
.Internal(args(name))
<bytecode: 0x555948556d70>
<environment: namespace:base>
Error: unexpected end of input
Execution halted`

I will add a screenshot soon

Comment: No need for the screenshot.

Comment: Please try this. On the first line `args = commandArgs(TRUE)`, on the second line `print(args)`, and on the third line `print(paste("Length of args is:", length(args))`. Then if you can tell me + screen shot that, that will tell us a lot.

Comment: output:

`[1] "bam/G1_F121_A1.adapter_filtered2.mm10.clean_srt_markdup.bam"
[2] "Aneu_analysis"
[3] "/home/jah/blacklist/mm10-blacklist-v1_id.bed"
[4] "/home/jah/reference/UCSC_hg19_female.fa.fai"
Error: unexpected end of input
Execution halted`

screenshot

Comment: Okay we're getting somewhere. That's really weird. Something is wrong with the 5th argument...

Comment: Okay I think I worked it out...

Comment: In the last line of your bash script, try replacing `${name}` with `${Name}` (capitalize the N). Then I think everything should work

Comment: AMAZING! This worked, sorry I overlooked something so simple. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: With hindsight such things *seem* simple, but they are actually quite tricky to debug (and don't worry they happen to everyone from time to time). Very glad you solved it, well done on being persistent!